# Apache - Reverse proxy - Redirect without http or https

Tags: apache-2.2, reverse-proxy

I have header like this:

```
Connection  close
Content-Length  0
Content-Type    text/html; charset=utf-8
Date    Tue, 20 May 2014 09:46:35 GMT
Location    //example.com/file.php
Server  Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
Via 1.1 example-proxy.com
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.4.24
```

if the location has http or https prefix like this: `Location   http://example.com/file.php` then it works ok.

The most important is `Location //example.com/file.php` doesn't work.

This is my configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example-proxy.com
    ProxyVia On
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost Off
    RequestHeader set Host example.com
    RequestHeader unset Accept-Encoding
    SSLProxyEngine On
    ProxyHTMLMeta Off
    ProxyHTMLDocType XHTML
    <Proxy *>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
            AllowOverride None
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass / http://example.com/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://example.com/
    ProxyHTMLEnable On
    ProxyHTMLExtended On
    ProxyHTMLEvents content
    ProxyHTMLURLMap https://example.com/ https://example-proxy.com
    ProxyHTMLURLMap http://example.com/ https://example-proxy.com
    ProxyHTMLURLMap //example.com/ https://example-proxy.com
    ProxyHTMLURLMap example.com/ https://example-proxy.com
    ProxyHTMLURLMap example.com https://example-proxy.com </VirtualHost>
```

Please help... thanks alot.

Comment: This is not a valid `location`. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply. I'm config a reverse proxy but mod_proxy_html doesnt edit it to new url. it should be rewritten to proxied url `Location //example.com/file.php` => `Location //example-proxy.com/file.php` . I want to edit that header to proxied url :( - browser still understand `Location //example.com/file.php`